# Speech recognition is not underlining and providing alternate interpretations

Tags: voice-recognition

I just broke my Droid Turbo and replaced it with another of the same model. On both phones I was/am using Android 6.0.1. On my old phone, whenever I used  speech recognition, some of the words would be underlined. Whenever I clicked one of these underlined words, a list of other possible interpretations would come up. This was extremely helpful for correcting mistakes on the fly. However, on my new phone, this capability seems to be somehow disabled. I'm not sure if it's a setting or something, but it seems odd that I should have the same phone, backed up the way it was before to the best of my knowledge, but behaving differently. Any ideas on what can I do to get this function back? I tried searching for a solution, but it's a bit difficult when I have no idea what this functionality is officially called.....

Answer (score 0):

While it's unclear if you asking as development perspective or for using only. Knowing about the app /more information could be useful.
Here's a few information for you:
If development - yes, Google voice recognition returns more than one match. I think development is not reflected on question.

If app is showing only the first one/ result only then please check if it has the functionality to enable such feature(other results).

Thanks.